# Analysis of Liar-like sentences in fuzzy logic

Tags: logic, reference-request, paradox, semantics, non-classical-logic

Let *t*<sub>0</sub> = FALSE and *t*<sub>1</sub> = TRUE. In [fuzzy logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-fuzzy/), 0 or 1 can be switched out for any real number in the interval [0,1]. This lets us construct all manner of liar/honest-like sentences, ranging from, "This sentence maps to *t*<sub>0</sub>," to, "This sentence maps to *t*<sub>1</sub>."

I've read a lot about the liar paradox and its brethren, and one essay (Wojciech Żełaniec, "Why the 'veridic' is not any better than the 'liar'") about honest/truth-teller sentences, but I haven't seen anything about, say, "This sentence maps to *t*<sub>0.76549532...</sub>," or what. Are there analyses of these sentences in the literature?

EDIT: it seems like you could interpret *t*<sub>0.5+</sub> as "mostly true," so, "This sentence maps to *t*<sub>0.5+</sub>," could be read as, "This sentence is mostly true."

Comment: [The Liar and Related Paradoxes by Vezerides and Kehagias](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0309046) has extensive bibliographic remarks on the literature that treats the Liar in the context of fuzzy logic, "*the Liar and related self referential collections cease to be paradoxical in the context of fuzzy logic*". On Fuzzy Liars ("this sentence is 0.3 true") specifically see [Grim, 
Self-reference and chaos in fuzzy logic](http://pgrim.org/articles/self-referenceandchaosinfuzzylogic.pdf). One gets truth value oscillations as with the Liar, but with amplitude < 1.